# Mostrar información en base a un intervalo de tiempo específico

Tags: mysql

con una consulta:
He querido hacer una vista donde muestre los clientes que no devolvieron la película en un tiempo específico o solo no lo devolvieron, tengo la columna que es fecha salida de tipo **datetime** y los dias que se puede rentar en un **int**.
Estaba intentando sumar los días (**int**) a la fecha pero me devuelve todo en **Null**

```sql
    Select date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day) as Agregado
        From Renta
```

Intentando usar un where para comparar las fechas, pero me da error al no ser una columna

```sql
    Select date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day) as Agregado
        From Renta
    Where agregado < fechaDevolucion
```

Alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos.**

Hay diversas funciones para [manejo de fechas en mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html); en tu planteamiento mencionas la fecha de salida; omites la fecha en que devolvieron su valor por default, así que asumiendo es `null` te comento lo siguiente.

Ya tienes `fechaSalida` y `diasRenta`; y con (usare) `fechaDevolucion` en `null` *(para los casos que no ha sido regresada)*.

Una opción y la que te sugiero es que en los casos que `fechaDevolucion` sea `null` la fecha predeterminada sea **[NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)**; con lo anterior (digamos) ya no te preocupas para calcular *sin nada*; bastara usar una bandera.

```
SELECT
   fechaSalida, diasRenta,
   DATE_ADD(fechaSalida, INTERVAL diasRenta DAY) AS DebioDevolverse,
   IFNULL(fechaDevolucion, NOW()) AS fechaDevolucion,
   CASE WHEN fechaDevolucion IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END AS fueDevuelta
FROM
   Renta
WHERE
   DATEDIFF(IFNULL(fechaDevolucion, NOW()),fechaSalida)>diasRenta 
;
```

Lo que debes verificar es que tanto `fechaSalida` como `diasRenta` ninguno sea `null`. Con la sugerencia anterior obtendrás el material que no fue regresado a tiempo o hasta el momento no ha sido regresado; y para ello la columna `fueDevuelta` para *saberlo*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo acabo de probar y está excelente